# Changing Windows Registry to Change Mouse Pointer with Python Not Updating Mouse Pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simple program that changes the mouse pointer in Windows to a custom .cur image using Python (yes I know you can easily do this via Control Panel but I am using this as a learning tool).

Here is the sample code I used to re-write the registry (will fix wildcard import in final version):

```
from winreg import *
k = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Control Panel\Cursors',0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
SetValueEx(k, 'Arrow',0, REG_SZ, '%SYSTEMROOT%\\Cursors\\rick_serious.cur')
```

At this point, the registry updates successfully. However, the mouse pointer does not get updated.

After extensive googling, I found this article that explains you need to call a function to "update" the cursor:
[link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/01/17/use-powershell-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-scheme/)

However, I'm lost as to how to use the SystemParametersInfo function in Python. I came across pypiwin32. However, when I go to the [documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__SystemParametersInfo_meth.html) and search for SystemParametersInfo, there is no "SPI_SETCURSORS" action available (as explained in that article).

Is there another way to SPI_SETCURSORS?

If it's possible to do it with this library and I'm not seeing it, could you provide an example as I find this documentation hard to read.

I know the 3 lines of code above don't look like much but several hours of research went into it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way using ctypes. The following line of code updates the cursor which is what you do after setting the registry. The parameters were obtained from Microsoft's website:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(0x0057, 0, None, 0)
```